# Get simple average from collection with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregate, spring-data-mongodb

I need to get the average duration of all the iterations made. I have the entity entity that I explain below:

```
@Document(collection = IterationEntity.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class IterationEntity {

    public final static String COLLECTION_NAME = "iterations";

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Field("start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Field("finish_date")
    private Date finishDate;

    @Field("duration")
    private Long duration;

    @Field("total_tasks")
    private Integer totalTasks = 0;

    @Field("total_failed_tasks")
    private Integer totalFailedTasks = 0;

    @Field("total_comments")
    private Integer totalComments = 0;

    @Field("tasks")
    @DBRef
    @CascadeSave
    private Set<TaskEntity> tasks = new HashSet<>();

}
```

I have implemented a custom repository method to perform this operation but I get an error when I get the result.

```
@Override
    public Long getAvgDuration() {

        GroupOperation avgOperation = Aggregation.group()
            .sum("duration")
                .as("total_duration")
            .avg("total_duration")
                .as("avg_duration");

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(IterationEntity.class, avgOperation);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, IterationEntity.COLLECTION_NAME, Long.class).getUniqueMappedResult();

    }
```

When the method is executed I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for java.lang.Long
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In above aggregation query, you are returning both sum & average, while you have given  Long as a class type to function  mongoTemplate.aggregate. I think that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to map the aggregation result correctly it needs to be mapped to a domain type or simply the `Document` returned.
Something like below should do what you're looking for.

```
class AggResult {
  @Field("total_duration") Long duration;
  @Field("avg_duration") Double avgDuration;
}

return template
  .aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION_NAME, AggResult.class)
  .getUniqueMappedResult()
  .getAvgDuration();
```